# how to filter html mail as replies with regex in php

Tags: php, regex, filter

I`m receiving html mail like this

```
<div dir="ltr">last message</div>
<div class="gmail_extra">
    <br>
    <div class="gmail_quote">
        2016-04-09 16:30 GMT+04:00
        <span dir="ltr">&lt;<a href="mailto:mymail@example.com" target="_blank">mymail@example.com</a>&gt;</span>:
        <br>
        <blockquote class="gmail_quote" style="margin:0 0 0 .8ex;border-left:1px #ccc solid;padding-left:1ex">
            <div class="HOEnZb">
                <div class="h5">
                    On 2016-04-09 13:05, repliername repliersurname wrote:<br>
                    <blockquote class="gmail_quote" style="margin:0 0 0 .8ex;border-left:1px #ccc solid;padding-left:1ex">
                        the third reply message text<br>
                        On Fri, Apr 8, 2016 at 10:47 PM, &lt;<a href="mailto:mymail@example.com" target="_blank">mymail@example.com</a>&gt; wrote:<br>
                        <br>
                        <blockquote class="gmail_quote" style="margin:0 0 0 .8ex;border-left:1px #ccc solid;padding-left:1ex">
                            On 2016-04-08 21:14, repliername repliersurname wrote:<br>
                            <br>
                            <blockquote class="gmail_quote" style="margin:0 0 0 .8ex;border-left:1px #ccc solid;padding-left:1ex">
                                the first reply message text<br>
                            </blockquote>
                            <br>
                            the second reply message text<br>
                        </blockquote>
                    </blockquote>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            the fourth reply message text<br>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

I need to filter this string in php array with replies...
the result must be like this

```
$mail = [
            "content" => "last message",
            "replies" => [
                "date" => "2016-04-09 16:30",
                "from" => "mymail@example.com",
                "content" => "the fourth reply message text",                
                "reply" => [
                    "date" => "016-04-09 13:05",
                    "from" => "repliername repliersurname",
                    "content" => " the third reply message text",
                    "reply" => [
                        "date" => "2016-04-08 22:47",
                        "from" => "mymail@example.com",
                        "content" => "the second reply message text",
                        "reply" => [
                            "date" => "2016-04-08 21:14",
                            "from" => "repliername repliersurname",
                            "content" => "the first reply message text"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

and it must filter with regular expresion...
please help me...
I do not know hot to do this...

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem with regex...

```
preg_match('#<blockquote[^>]+>(.+?)</blockquote>#ims', $text, $matches);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($matches);
```